# Zend Form W3C validation with HTML5 Doctype

Tags: html, zend-form, w3c-validation

I am using decorators for my forms in a Zend Framework (version 1.10.6) application and they output elements with attribute **helper** that W3C finds invalid against HTML5 Doctype.

```
<input type="hidden" name="control" value="search" helper="formHidden" id="control">
```

W3C Validator is giving me this error:
**Attribute helper not allowed on element input at this point.**

Comment: Well, it *is* invalid. Can you change it to `data-helper`? That'd be allowed.

Comment: I tried everything but it didn't work, and I still don't know what this helper attribute is used for by Zend Framework so I decided to remove it completely from the core since I don't know any other viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing I found about this issue is working so after many hours of trying different approaches I found it easier to change the core (yes, I know it's not recommended but it is still a solution).

Here is the answer (for input hidden):

- go to **Zend/View/Helper/FormHidden.php**
- at the end of the file you will find this line of code

  ```
  return $this->_hidden($name, $value, $attribs);
  ```
- add this code **BEFORE** it

  ```
  unset($attribs['helper']);
  ```

What it does is remove the helper attribute from the array of attributes applied to the input hidden element.

The same applies for all form elements.

Example for input text:

- go to **Zend/View/Helper/FormText.php**
- at the end of the file you will find these lines of code

  ```
  $xhtml = '<input type="text"'
         . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
         . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
         . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($value) . '"'
         . $disabled
         . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
         . $endTag;

  return $xhtml;
  ```
- add this code **BEFORE** it

  ```
  unset($attribs['helper']);
  ```

Doing this for all form elements my website passed W3C HTML5 validation, so I am satisfied with this solution and hope it gets resolved with Zend Framework 2.0

Comment: This is a very, very bad answer. NEVER edit framework source code, only extend their classes and change the way it works.